# How to find duplicate / non distinct values with xpath

Tags: xpath, duplicates, distinct-values

Given the following example html:

```xml
<products>
  <product>
    <sku>10021</sku>
  </product>
  <product>
    <sku>10021</sku>
  </product>
  <product>
    <sku>10022</sku>
  </product>
  <product>
    <sku>10023</sku>
  </product>
  <product>
    <sku>10023</sku>
  </product>
</products>
```

I know how to find distinct sku values with xpath: `distinct-values(//sku)`, which will output:

```
10021
10022
10023
```

But how would I get the ones that are not distinct, so:

```
10021
10023
```

I am using xidel, so XPath 3 is fine. But if it can be done somehow with XPath 1, preferably without XSLT, I would very much like to read about that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one to get `sku` node with text that equal to text of at least one another `sku`:

```
distinct-values(//sku[.=following::sku])
```

You can also do it in XPath 1 like this:

```
//sku[.=preceding::sku and not(.=following::sku)]
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. I fiddled around with it a bit to get it to work with xpath 1. I have suggested an edit to your answer, can you accept it please, so I can mark it as correct?